# Mono-energetic anti neutrino spectrum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics

Are there any nuclear decays that produce a mono-energetic anti-neutrino spectrum? I suspect that there aren't any but I can't justify why.

Comment: [Two-body beta decays](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147619/44126) would have a monoenergetic antineutrino spectrum, but the examples given in the answers to that question would have a large continuous-energy antineutrino background from the more common three-body decay.