# How is Electron emitted in a Beta Decay?

Tags: radioactivity

In a beta decay , a neutron converts into proton and an electron. 
By [image]

How is one extra electron created? Are two electrons created by one neutron?

Comment: A neutron consists of two down quarks and one up quark, the proton consists of two up quarks and one down quark. Beta decay proceeds as explained in [this picture](https://home.fnal.gov/~cheung/rtes/RTESWeb/LQCD_site/objects/betadecay.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is an atom charged after undergoing beta emission?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/147619/is-an-atom-charged-after-undergoing-beta-emission)

Comment: Please mark up your math using mathjax, and don't use images for equations. Images don't work with search engines, and they don't work for blind people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how [a beta decay](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Nuclear/beta.html) proceeds:

[image: beta-]

note that the neutron turns into a proton, and electron and an electron antineutrino.

This increases the Z, i.e. the positive charge of the nucleus. The new *atom* becomes positive. If the energy of the electron produced is small, it will fill up the hole in the electron structure.Otherwise the *atom*  will attract an electron from the ones in the fermi level, if it is a metal, or a positive hole will exist if it is an insulator.

Answer (score -1):

Weak interaction doesnt vilote the law of conservation of charge so if a neutron is converted into a proton (for more stable nucleus ) then an electron must be created.

Comment: The OP knows that an electron is created. They're asking if *two* electrons are created.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The OP knows that the A nucleus converts into the B nucleus by converting a neutron into a proton & emitting an electron. But a neutral B atom has 1 more electron than a neutral A atom, so where does that extra electron come from?

Comment: In beta minus decay the atom is transformed to another atom with the number of protons reduced by 1.If the new atom isnt happy to be positively charged in comparison with his nearby atoms then it receives one electron to become more stable.

Comment: Yes sorry increased by 1

Comment: I was careless.